# Source for 71% of the earth being water

Tags: water, land-surface

It is commonly known that 71% of the earth’s surface is covered by water. What sources can I look at that explain this calculation in more detail?

Comment: It isn't a calculation, it is just a fact. You just measure which fraction of the earth surface is covered by water, and which fraction is land. You can do that with any map you want as long as you remember what projection the map uses.

Comment: Sounds like a very reasonable question to me.  May wind up being more suitable for gis, as I'd figure that's a basic way to show that solution.